# How can I give FTP access to multiple folders in cPanel?

Tags: cpanel, ftp, directory, path

I am trying to create a FTP account in cPanel, and give it FTP access to multiple directories.

There are a lot of folders, but I only want to give the user access to two of them. I know how to give access to single folder or all of the folders, but I have no idea about how to do with multiple ones.

BTW, I do not know about Linux...

Comment: What server access do you have? Only cPanel?

Comment: This isn't possible directly with cPanel, see [here](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/mulitple-folders-allowed-via-ftp) as to why. Try the answer and comments [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1026691/how-to-allow-ftp-user-acess-folder-outside-his-root-directory).

Comment: @w3dk Thanks for replying! I only use cPanel, but I use Filezilla to upload and download files.

Comment: @dan Thanks for your reply! And I do feel that it might be impossible to do it with cPanel, and I also view the link you shared, unfortunately, I do not know Linux, so it is kind of hard for me to try it... Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have version 64.0.22 you can create a web disk and set a directory for each user. Which they are able to view download edit from their PC mobile or other software.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Web%20Disk#